# Getting error only some of the time when calculating: "Undefined method '/' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, calculated-columns

I'm using Ruby on Rails and am iterating through an object.

I want to display a percentage from dividing two columns' value then multiplying by 100.

I don't know if I can just write it in the view or if I need to write a method in the model or controller. I first chose to write it in the view and am getting an error "Undefined method "/" for nil:NilClass" only some of the time.

I think that's an error that's thrown when there is no value for one of the columns. When I write the method in the model or controller, there is no error but the value I'm trying to display is blank.

Here's how my calculation looks in the view:

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= number_to_percentage(object.column1 / object.column2.round(2) * 100, precision: 0) %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` is a method like any other in Ruby and `a / b` is just a different way of saying `a./(b)` so that error is telling you that `object.column1` is `nil`.

You have to decide what you want `object.column1.nil` to mean:

- Do you display such things specially? If so then:

  ```
  <% if object.column1.nil? %>
    nil or whatever else you want to say
  <% else %>
    <%= object.column1 / object.column2.round(2) * 100, precision: 0) %>
  <% end %>
  ```
- Do you want to treat `nil` like zero? If so then:

  ```
  <%= object.column1.to_i / object.column2.round(2) * 100, precision: 0) %>
  ```

  You'd want to use `to_f` instead of `to_i` if the `column1` is a floating point value. If `n` is an integer then `n.to_i == n` but `nil.to_i == 0` so `to_i` is a convenient way to hide the common "treat `nil` as `0`" logic; similarly for `floating_point_value.to_f` and `nil.to_f`.

If `object.column2` can also be `nil` then you have to make similar decisions about how to handle `object.column2.nil?`.

Comment: I think that did it! I tried a simiar if/else statement and that threw an error on any columns that did not have a value yet since the value is dependent on a form being completed. All I had to do was add `to_i` after `object.column1`. Thank you so much!